# Using venturi effect for equilibrating pressure drop

Tags: fluid-mechanics, airflow

Let me first say I am a novice in fluid dynamics, I am not sure about terminology but I will try to explain myself as clearly as possible.

I need some help for understanding the following case: in a air circuit (figure below) there are two pipes with two head losses $\Delta P_1 >\Delta P_2$. I need for the two velocities $v_1$ and $v_2$ to be greater then 0.5 m/s.
As the head loss for $v_1$ is bigger, we have $v_1<v_2$ and adding more energy (using a bigger fan) to the circuit does not solve the problem.

[image: Fig. 1]

So a solution would be to increase $\Delta P_2$ (and the initial speed) until we get the velocities which we need.

My question is: **can we achieve the same (increasing $v_1$ to 0.5 m/s) without increasing $\Delta P_2$ using a Venturi for sucking air in the first pipe (figure below)?**
Does this solution require less energy than the first one?

[image: Fig. 2]

Comment: please describe more what we are doing here.  Increasing V1 means increasing mass flow rate.  Are we trying to increase the flow rate or the flow rate over a sensor?  Increasing flow rate means increasing inlet pressure, which you can get either from a higher pressure inlet or by throttling V2

Comment: Yes, I need to increase $v_1$ and so the flow rate